# Multi-Threading and Asynchronous sockets in python

Tags: python, multithreading, asynchronous, network-programming

I'm quite new to python threading/network programming, but have an assignment involving both of the above.
One of the requirements of the assignment is that for each new request, I spawn a new thread, but I need to both send and receive at the same time to the browser.
I'm currently using the asyncore library in Python to catch each request, but as I said, I need to spawn a thread for each request, and I was wondering if using both the thread and the asynchronous is overkill, or the correct way to do it? 
Any advice would be appreciated.
Thanks

EDIT:
I'm writing a Proxy Server, and not sure if my client is persistent. My client is my browser (using firefox for simplicity)
It seems to reconnect for each request. My problem is that if I open a tab with http://www.google.com in it, and http://www.stackoverflow.com in it, I only get one request at a time from each tab, instead of multiple requests from google, and from SO.

Comment: The title of this sounds like a bad joke. If you really decide you cannot solve this problem any other way, check out a networking lib like Twisted to try to add some sanity.

Comment: Can't use twisted, as it does it for me. I need code more than that myself

Comment: Assignment like homework? I think there is a tag for that.

Comment: Yep, sorry about that, changed now!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I answered a question that sounds amazingly similar to your, where someone had a homework assignment to create a client server setup, with each connection being handled in a new thread: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9522339/496445

The general idea is that you have a main server loop constantly looking for a new connection to come in. When it does, you hand it off to a thread which will then do its own monitoring for new communication.

*An extra bit about asyncore vs threading*

From the [asyncore docs](http://docs.python.org/library/asyncore.html):

> There are only two ways to have a program on a single processor do
>   “more than one thing at a time.” Multi-threaded programming is the
>   simplest and most popular way to do it, but there is another very
>   different technique, that lets you have nearly all the advantages of
>   multi-threading, without actually using multiple threads. It’s really
>   only practical if your program is largely I/O bound. If your program
>   is processor bound, then pre-emptive scheduled threads are probably
>   what you really need. Network servers are rarely processor bound,
>   however.

As this quote suggests, using asyncore and threading should be for the most part mutually exclusive options. My link above is an example of the threading approach, where the server loop (either in a separate thread or the main one) does a blocking call to accept a new client. And when it gets one, it spawns a thread which will then continue to handle the communication, and the server goes back into a blocking call again.

In the pattern of using asyncore, you would instead use its async loop which will in turn call your own registered callbacks for various activity that occurs. There is no threading here, but rather a polling of all the open file handles for activity. You get the sense of doing things all concurrently, but under the hood it is scheduling everything serially.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but solved my problem nonetheless.

Comment: Glad it helped solve your problem at least. I didn't think it was exactly a 1-to-1 solution for you, but I saw it as a pretty complete example of doing client/server sockets with a thread being started for each new client connection.

Comment: I had done a client-server before, but this was spawning a new thread for each browser request.
Actually, unrelated to the question, how would I go about speeding up the queueing of requests from the browser, as it only seems to load up one request from each tab at a time.... for instance, if I load google in one tab and SO in another, I get two requests at a time, but never 4 or 5 from google at once and 4 or 5 from SO at the same time..

Comment: Up until this point I wasn't sure what kind of server you were even creating. Is your client a persistant connection? Does it reconnect for every request, thus a connection == request? If your "tab" with google only creates a single client connection to the server then it only has one pipe and all requests have to go through serially. On the server side, it can be set up to work on each read() from the client serially, or again, spawned into a thread with the data read. You still have to actually do the read() one at a time obviously.

Comment: Edited the question to try and clarify what I'm asking.

Comment: When you say you only get one at a time, do you flat out only get one req from each tab and thats it? Or do you mean they go back and forth and you ultimately get multiple requests? If you are setting the browser to use your server as a proxy, then its up to the browser how it will issue the requests.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/9384/discussion-between-jdi-and-maccard)