# Python create many connections in parallel via Curl or Socket

Tags: python, xml, sockets, curl, persistent

I'm a newbie with python, so I need your help.

What is the best solution to create a multi connections to a target server?? Threading? Using socket? using Curl? others lib?

I try to explain:

I need to connect via ssl to a server,  post an xml string that login

After that I need to send 1000 more xml string, it a command (EPP command) ... this is always post, always the same xml every time.

At the end I need to post another xml, for logout.

Can you show me an example ?

Also I need these connection is persistent so the server don't break it.

Thanks to all

Comment: Example ---> `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9521113/thread-synchronization-python/9522339#9522339`

Comment: Thanks for this link, I saw that thread,  but I need more details for understand it :(

Answer (score 0):

Example of using [threads](http://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html):

```
import threading

def async(target_func):
    """executes function asynchronously in a separate thread """
    def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
        thread = threading.Thread(target=target_func, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
        thread.daemon = True
        thread.start()
    return wrapper

@async
def send_xml():
    #do something
    pass
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this code.... Can you give me an example more complete??  I'm really new to python :(

With this example values:

server to call:   https://epp-test.nic-test.cz   (is an example)

Xml for login :  <command>LoginUser;LoginPass</command>

Xml command to send 1000 times in parallel :  <command>create_domain:testtesttest.cz</command>

Xml for logut :  <command>Logout</command>

Thanks

Comment: it's out of the question scope. Actually, all you need is just to copy and paste examples of urllib usage: http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html

Comment: You also have to mind that if you want to maintain persistent connection using this approach you will have to run all the 1000 requests in a single thread. However you can handle several sessions of 1k requests ongoing in parallel in separate threads